# Does energy conversion always requires Kinetic energy in some manner to be present?

Tags: thermodynamics

Does energy always needs to be converted into Kinetic form in order to convert into another form? What I mean, is Kinetic energy meta form for all energy conversion? As we can see for electricity to light up the bulb the electrons has to be set into motion. Also in Nuclear power plants we basically covert the nuclear tension among the atoms into kinetic form which heats off the turbine in turn produces the energy

Answer (score 1):

To put the point another way, energy transfer always requires motion. In an entirely motionless environment, there can be no energy transfer. Given that motion equates to KE, KE is always involved in the transfer of energy.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had been stuck with this for days now. Was really hard to explain my point!! Am grateful you understood the problem

Answer (score 1):

The broad energy forms are mechanical, thermal, electromagnetic, electrical, chemical, and nuclear. But they all boil down to one of two fundamental forms: Kinetic (energy of motion) and Potential (energy of position).

Consequently, conversions between the broad forms of energy must boil down to either kinetic to kinetic, kinetic to potential, potential to kinetic, or potential to potential. Even potential to potential conversions (e.g, gravitational potential energy to elastic potential energy) involve some form of motion (kinetic energy) during the conversion.

So to answer your question, yes, it would appear that all energy conversions involve kinetic energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe radiation energy (photons) would be a third form, or should it be lumped into some type of radiative potential of a field?  E=h$\nu$. Where's the potential or the kinetic?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I was really stuck with the problem and was unable to explain the situation for days. I am grateful to you for your insight.